# Highstock returns incorrect x value (datetime) after zoom for column chart

Tags: highcharts

After any sort of zoom (mouse drag, range selector, date input) the datetime returned from the point click event is usually incorrect. I've not yet found this problem when using an area chart, have found it using both bar and column chart.
 
To recreate: run the fiddle, zoom using the mouse across a few of the columns, click a datapoint. The alert will show the datetime returned. Notice it's different from the tooltip (which is correct).
Usually fails after first click, even for the same datapoint.

BTW useUTC setting doesn't matter.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrEDT/

Code for completeness:

```
$(function() {
var seriesOptions = [],
    yAxisOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT'],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',   function(data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            type: 'column'
        };

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter++;

        if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});

// create the chart when all data is loaded
function createChart() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false // datetime reflects time on db (ie, local) rather than GMT
        }
    });
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },
        yAxis: {
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }],
            offset: 25
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var series = this.series.name;
                            var utc = this.x;
                            var d = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x);
                           alert(d);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter:function(a,b,c){
                var d = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x);
                return d;
            },
            enable:true
        },
        series: seriesOptions
    });
}
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same issue with this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/8htkj/ ? All I have done is removed exporting options (there were errors in console)

Comment: Same problem. You can try yourself; please let me know if I haven't made the procedure clear. Mainly: zoom with mouse, click and compare tooltip data vs returned data from click event. They don't match.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I should have said "compare tooltip DATE vs returned DATE .."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I have filled report: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1526

Comment: Thank you! Do you work for highslide? Just wondering if filing a report is something I could do. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Yes, as Highcharts/Highstock supporter. Adding reports is available for everyone, but Highcharts has many options, and if each 'bug' will be reported there, instead of using SO, we will have mess there.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable datagrouping http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping ?

Comment: Can't disable dataGrouping because in my real live production chart we have tens of thousands of data points.

Comment: But it was worth a try, so I just did .. doesn't fix the problem. I consider it a bug rather than a question and understood that the HighStock folks monitor this forum .. at least that's what this says: http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=12 .. of course it could be MY bug ;->